# Shopify CLI seems unable to find Ruby on Mac

Tags: shopify, homebrew

I installed `shopify-cli` using `homebrew` on my Mac and tried verifying the installation by running `shopify version`, but I get an error:

```
/usr/local/bin/shopify: line 2: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.0.1/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
```

Any idea what needs to be fixed?

Comment: make sure you have Ruby installed? The error is pretty clear that for whatever reason, you currently don't have a valid Ruby for your shell operations.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Macs come with Ruby preinstalled. In any case, if I run `ruby -v`, it outputs `ruby 3.0.2p107 (2021-07-07 revision 0db68f0233) [arm64-darwin21]`. I assume Ruby is installed, but probably at a location/path other than where shopify-cli expects to find it...

Answer (score 1):

Try running `brew install ruby@3.0`. It worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

It appears that `shopify-cli` was installed when your Homebrew `ruby` was at version 3.0.1. This can be fixed by running the following command:

```
brew reinstall shopify-cli
```

(Ideally, the `shopify-cli` formula should be updated by its maintainers to replace hardcoded `ruby` paths to the version-agnostic `/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby`. Alternatively, they could track the Homebrew `ruby` version and bump the revision of `shopify-cli` whenever an update occurs. This will prompt end-users to run `brew upgrade`, which will automatically reinstall `shopify-cli`.)

Comment: I tried reinstalling as per your suggestion. However, the problem persists...

Comment: I noticed that the error references both `/usr/local` (Intel Homebrew) and `/opt/homebrew` (Apple Silicon Homebrew). Is it possible you have `shopify-cli` installed twice?

Comment: Is there a way I can check and, if so, uninstall both and install just the one needed?

Comment: `arch -arm64e brew list --versions shopify-cli` and `arch -x86_64 brew list --versions shopify-cli` should do the trick. Uninstall by running the same `arch` with `brew uninstall shopify-cli`. Also what is your output for `readlink /usr/local/bin/shopify`?

Comment: Output of `readlink /usr/local/bin/shopify` is `/opt/homebrew/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/shopify-cli-1.13.1/bin/shopify.sh`

Comment: And output for both `arch` commands is `shopify-cli 2.7.1`

Comment: Oh. It seems you have it installed as a Ruby gem. You can verify this by running `gem list -i "^shopify-cli$"` and to uninstall, run `gem uninstall shopify-cli`

Comment: Oh sweet, you are a life-saver. Having uninstalled the gem-version of `shopify cli`, running `shopify version` instantly logged the version. Thank you!